# How to check network resource loaded correctly from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with many resources loaded.

I would like to know if there is any way to know when a resource loaded correctly from javascript.

I have:

```
index.html
```

and

```
<script src="myResource.js"></script>
```

How can I know from javascript that myResource is correctly loaded without searching for some variable inside of myResource file.

I would like to do something like:

```
window.network.isLoaded("myResource.js") ? 'it is loaded!' : 'it is not loaded';
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with `load` event listener:

```
var $script = document.querySelector("[src='myResource.js']");

$script.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // your callback's code
});
```

---

As it has been pointed out by @pwolaq, this code won't work when the script has already been loaded.

To overcome this problem, you can use event delegation & event capturing (and make sure this code is placed **before** your script definition):

```
var $document = document.querySelector("body");

document.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
    var $script = document.querySelector("script[src='myResource.js']");

    if (!evt.target.isEqualNode($script) {
        return;
    }

    // Callback code
}, true);
```

Comment: That's because your resource has been loaded already - therefore, the event has been emitted before you've attached your listener. Try attaching it before your ``<script>`` tag definition.

Comment: how do you want to attach listener to script before it's definition? you would have to insert it by javascript itself...

Comment: Using event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally scripts are loaded synchronously. So any script beneath:

```
 <script src="myResource.js"></script>
```

Will have access to its predecessor variables and functions.
Better way is to check if resources that the script has loaded are present then the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Javascript.
For example, using jQuery:

```
$.getScript("myResource.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  if (jqxhr.status !== 200) {
    console.error('resource could not be loaded:', textStatus);
  }
});
```

Or, just with javascript:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
script.setAttribute("src", "myResource.js");
if (typeof script === "undefined") {
  console.error("resource could not be loaded");
} else {
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
if ($('script[src="myResource.js"]').length > 0){
    // script is loaded
}else{
    // not loaded
}
```

Hope it helps